# How to display HTML tags in UTF8 Translations in Template tool kit

Tags: html, perl, template-toolkit

I am working in a web based website, where we are using Perl, MySQL 5, Apache and Template Toolkit.
we are planning to introduce the support for multiple Language in our website.
What we have done is
IF we have a line in our template file, 
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`
`Download the "<a href="/help/materials/Brouchure_catalog.xls">Brouchure Catalog Sample</a>" as reference only purpose`
we have converted that to
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`
`<h1>[% glossary.$language.Brouchure_Catalog_Sample_info %].<\h1>`
where `$language` is getting the value which user selects when he logs in.
`$language` is the variable which is set according to the user's language preference.
Import excel looks like this:
[image: All translation are from Google Translator. Demo purpose only]
All translation are from Google Translator. Demo purpose only
This is how it appears in mysql DB:
[image]
Now the characters are appearing correctly in the website, but some translations which have HTML tags like this happening:
Download the "[Brouchure Catalog Sample](/help/materials/Brouchure_catalog.xls)" as reference only purpose
is appearing correctly in English language, but the same behaviour is not appearing for spanish language.
[image]

Is there some filters that can be used in these type of situation in template Tool kit? or anything wrong with the HTML

Comment: There are better more common and approved ways to handle translations. Have a look at [Locale::TextDomain](http://search.cpan.org/~guido/libintl-perl-1.23/lib/Locale/TextDomain.pm). It uses *.po files to store the translations. I can give a jump start if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Template toolkit dumper plugin

```
[% USE Dumper %]
```

to show your 'glossary'

```
[% Dumper.dump(glossary) %]
```

in your template. Maybe the glossary is not filled propperly.

Comment: thanks for directing me to the issue. I had not tried dumper in template. Here is what i am getting when I dump that variable on screen. \x{62a}\x{62d}\x{645}\x{64a}\x{644}</a>\\\"\x{627}\x{633}\x{62a}\x{64a}\x{631}\x{627}\x{62f} \x{643}\x{62a}\x{627}\x{644}\x{648}\x{62c} \x{645}\x{644}\x{639}\x{628} \x{639}\x{64a}\x{646}\x{629} \x{627}\x{644}\x{645}\x{644}\x{641}\\\"<a href=\\\"/help/materials/import/examples/course_catalog.xls\\\"> \x{643}\x{645}\x{631}\x{62c}\x{639} \x{627}\x{644}\x{63a}\x{631}\x{636} \x{627}\x{644}\x{648}\x{62d}\x{64a}\x{62f}

Answer (score 0):

The only way this was achievable was by removing the HTML components from the Translation.

Download the "[Brouchure Catalog Sample](/help/materials/Brouchure_catalog.xls)" as reference only purpose

we have converted that to

[% glossary.$language.Download_the %] "[[% glossary.$language.Brouchure_Catalog_Sample %]](/help/materials/Brouchure_catalog.xls)[% glossary.$language.as_reference_only_purpose %].

If you are thinking that the splitting of the sentence will get jumbled up, you are wrong. I was also in the same assumption before. Later when I tried, The Browser does a pretty good job in converting and retaining the order in the expected format.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.katpatuka.org/pub/doc/content-language/ar.htm

here you go, I hope that helps you :-)

Comment: If I change that the arabic or spanish acute characters would be displayed I suppose